# Project "Templates" in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, project

I am structuring given code base for iOS, which is used to create two kinds of apps, which share common functionality. The new structure would ideally look like this:

```
×-> General Implementation        <-------------×
|                                               |
×-- GeneralMainProject Implementation   <---×   SomeProjectX Implementation
                                            |
    MainProjectVersionX Implementation  ----×
```

where each Implementation may include classes subclassing classes from upper level, and set of utility classes.

The problem is, that when I want to use a subclass, I would have to override every single use of it (for example, in GeneralMainProject AppDelegate).

Any idea how to solve this, with technology or different design? Class posing and categories don't help, because they would require dictionary of fields and or runtime disadvantages.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite get what your problem is, hence not an answer. For a similar(?) setup, I have a preconstructed WTG_Framework class, and require that applications supply a WTG_Project class which is derived from WTG_Framework, although the main reason for this naming requirement is because an instance WTG_Project will be constructed during startup (and older version of this called an application-defined factory function to do this, which is also how I do it in C++)

Comment: Make a static library, because it's way too much work to make a template,